# Why isn't the "a" article added before the phrase "slightly different terminology"?

Tags: indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns

I would like to know why the "a" article hasn't been added before the phrase "slightly different terminology" in this paragraph:

> So, you can create exactly the Employee — Manager example, but you use **slightly different terminology**.

are adding it is correct as well as not or what the hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"terminology" can be countable or uncountable.

**Examples**

*You use a slightly different terminology.* (countable)

*You use slightly different terminology.* (uncountable)